# How do you align 3 DIV's side by side inside of another DIV and right justify the last DIV?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a simple list item that I want to format.  It contains 3 DIV's.  I want the first DIV to be left justified, the second DIV to be able to grow as needed, and the third DIV to be right justified. I have the three DIV's stacked side by side, but I can't figure out how to get the last DIV to right justify.  This is what it looks like now:

[image]

```
<li *ngFor="let script of scripts" [class.selected]="script === selectedScript" (click)="onSelect(script)">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="badge">{{script.scriptOrderID}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <span>{{script.scriptName}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <span class="badge2">{{script.scriptID}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

This is what I want it to look like:
[image]

```
.container { 
display: flex;
}

.left { 
width: 70px;
}

.center{ 
display: flex;
}

.right{
}
```

Comment: Please post your css also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at **flexbox**, easy to use, and with flex-end it'll be fast to get your blocks at the end.

```
<div class="line">
  <div class="first_block">

  </div>
  <div class="text">
      Hello
  </div>
  <div class="second_block">

  </div>
</div>


.line {
  height : 40px;
  width : 100%;
  display : flex;
  flex-flow : row wrap;
  background-color : gray;
}

.first_block, .second_block {
  background-color : blue;
  width : 40px;
}

.text {
  flex-grow : 1;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vpzx82ez/) to show you the result.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without all the divs in the li...
Display your list-item as table, and the span's inside it as table-cell:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; box-sizing: border-box; }

ul {
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
li > span {
  display: table-cell;
  background: lightgrey;
}
li > span:first-child,
li > span:last-child {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>60</span>
    <span>Click Add a Printer</span>
    <span>53</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>70</span>
    <span>Click "The printer I want isn't listed"</span>
    <span>54</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>80</span>
    <span>Select "Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname" Click Next</span>
    <span>55</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

## Flexbox alternativ

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; box-sizing: border-box; }

ul {
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
li > span {
  background: lightgrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
li > span:first-child,
li > span:last-child {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 3em;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>60</span>
    <span>Click Add a Printer</span>
    <span>53</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>70</span>
    <span>Click "The printer I want isn't listed"</span>
    <span>54</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>80</span>
    <span>Select "Add a printer using a TCP/IP address or hostname" Click Next</span>
    <span>55</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like below.

You have fixed width divs on both sides and a center div with fluid width.

That should do the trick.

```css
.container > div {
float: left;
padding: 0 10px;
}

.left{
width: 30px;
}
.right {
width: 30px;
}

.center {
width: calc( 100% - 120px);
background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="left">
          <span class="badge">23</span>
        </div>
        <div class="center">
          <span>test</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <span class="badge2">44</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `flexbox` you can do this:

```css
.container {
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.center {
  flex: 1;
}
.badge,
.badge2 {
  display: block;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <span class="badge">*</span>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <span>The Name will grow</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <span class="badge2">**</span>
  </div>
</div>
```